# How to calculate the rolling mean for particular columns and need to print rolling mean with along with date

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series, data-science

I have dataframe with columns label app_name, date and gross revenue, calculated the rolling mean for gross revenue with window 2.
I am very new to this

```
 App_Name           Date        Gross Revenue
com.alpha.studio    2018-10-16   11643154
com.alpha.studio    2018-10-17   13198984
com.alpha.studio    2018-10-18   24217875
```

I wrote code somthing like this

```
rolling_mean = com_fivemobile_thescore['Gross Revenue'].astype(int).rolling(2).mean()
rolling_std = com_fivemobile_thescore['Gross Revenue'].astype(int).rolling(2).std()
print ("mean and std----------",rolling_mean)
```

Getting somethong like this

```
65259     3352.5
231872    3245.5
226967    1936.0
162993    2583.0
237743    3190.5
228604    2550.5
219176    1698.0
```

Expected format is: I need rolling mean with date

```
            Date        Gross Revenue
   1             NaN
   2018-10-16    3352.5
   2018-10-17    3245.5
   2018-10-18    2583.0
```

please help to solve this

Comment: Again, why did your question get 3 upvotes in ONE minute? Your previous question received 4 upvotes in 3 minutes. This is unheard of in this tag.

Answer (score 2):

You could set the Date as the index and then compute the moving average:

```
com_fivemobile_thescore.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
rolling_mean = com_fivemobile_thescore['Gross Revenue'].rolling(2).mean()
```

If you don't want to keep the Date as the index for the final format, you can just reset index.

```
rolling_mean = rolling_mean.reset_index(drop=False)
```

Comment: @K Zhao when I try to reset the index getting following error
raise TypeError('Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series '
TypeError: Cannot reset_index inplace on a Series to create a DataFrame

Comment: It looks like you cannot use 'inplace' in this case. You can just create a new variable. I've edited my answer.